# С++ builder RSA не работает при заданных числах

Tags: c++builder, криптография, rsa

**Рекомендуемые значения параметров p=113, q=281, e=3. Почему не работает при заданных числах(при больших работает)?**

1.Алгоритм Евклида - нахождение НОД 2 целых чисел

```
int nod(int a, int b)
    {
        int c;
        while (b)
        {
            c = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = c;        
        }
        return abs(a);
    }

   int main()
{
int p_simple = 113;
int q_simple = 281;
```

2.Находим число n.

```
 unsigned int n = p_simple*q_simple;
```

3.Генерация числа d и проверка его на взаимопростоту с числом z.

```
int d, d_simple = 0;
    while (d_simple !=1)
    {
        d = rand()%100;
        d_simple = nod (d, ((p_simple-1)*(q_simple-1)));
    }
```

4.Определение числа e, для которого является истинным соотношение (e*d)%z=1.

```
 unsigned int e = 0, e_simple = 0;
    while (e_simple !=1)
    {
        e += 1;
        e_simple = (e*d)%((p_simple-1)*(q_simple-1));
    }
    // int e=3;
```

5.Сгенерированные ключи.

```
  cout << '{' << setw(12) << e << ',' << setw(12) << n << '}' << " - Open key (e,n)" << endl;
  cout << '{' << setw(12) << d << ',' << setw(12) << n << '}' << " - Personal key (d,n)" << endl << endl;
```

6.Ввод шифруемых данных.

```
  const int MAX = 20;
        char *Text = new char [MAX];
        cout << "Please enter the Text. Use <Enter> button when done." << endl;
        cin.get(Text, MAX);
```

7.Массив для хранения шифротекста.

```
unsigned int *CryptoText = new unsigned int [MAX];
unsigned int *Tdecrypt = new unsigned int [MAX];
```

8.Получение из введённых данных десятичного кода ASCII и дальнейшее его преобразование по формуле ci = (mj^e)%n.

```
int b = 301;
    int c;
    cout << endl << setw(5) << "Text" << setw(6) << "ASCII"
    << setw(20) <<"CryptoText/Block#" << setw(14)
    << "ASCIIdecrypt" << setw(14) << "Text decrypt" << endl
    << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        c = 1;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        int ASCIIcode = (static_cast<int>(Text[j]))+b;
            while (i<e)
            {
                c = c*ASCIIcode;
                c = c%n;
                i++;
            }
        CryptoText[j] = c;
        b+=1;
    }
```

9.Расшифровка полученного кода по формуле mi = (ci^d)%n и перевод его в десятичный код ASCII.

```
b = 301;
    int m;
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        m = 1;
        unsigned int i = 0;
            while (i<d)
            {
                m = m*CryptoText[j];
                m = m%n;
                i++;
            }
        m = m-b;
        Tdecrypt[j] = m;
        b+=1;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << Text[j] << setw(6) << static_cast<int>(Text[j]) << setw(20)
        << CryptoText[j] << setw(14) << Tdecrypt[j] << setw(14) << static_cast<char>(Tdecrypt[j]) << endl;
    }
        delete [] Text;
        delete [] CryptoText;
        delete [] Tdecrypt;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: И что, результат не сходится с оригиналом?

Comment: К сожалению изображения прикреплять нельзя,так бы можно было продемонстрировать. При случайном e исходный символ совпадает с расшифрованным, а при e=3 - нет.

Comment: @Nastre а зачем изображение? У Вас же вывод в консольное окно, копируйте оттуда текст, вставляйте в вопрос или комментарий. Копирование раньше было в угловом меню, левый верхний угол окна

Comment: Правильно:
{       12913,       31753} - Open key (e,n)
{          17,       31753} - Personal key (d,n)

Please enter the Text. Use <Enter> button when done.
RSA

 Text ASCII   CryptoText/Block#  ASCIIdecrypt  Text decrypt
------------------------------------------------------------
    R    82               27164            82             R
    S    83                5644            83             S
    A    65                5436            65             A

Comment: Ошибка при расшифровке:
{           3,       31753} - Open key (e,n)
{          17,       31753} - Personal key (d,n)

 Text ASCII   CryptoText/Block#  ASCIIdecrypt  Text decrypt
------------------------------------------------------------
    R    82               10830          1037
    S    83                6484          5402             →
    A    65               15575         31423             ┐

Answer (score 1):

Хе-хе... А кто сказал что будет работать? Вы откуда `e` берете? Сами таким сделали? Сколько будет `3 * 17 % (p-1)*(q-1)` ? Правильно, 3 * 17, и никаких 1.

А раз так, то и работать не будет. Если вам e нужен равным 3, то почему бы тогда d не рассчитывать так же, как вы сейчас e рассчитываете?

Не `d = rand()%100;`, а именно код, который для получения e используете.

P.S.: сорри за то, что тему поднял )